# Can't add foreign key constraint, (#1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint)

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to create a database, i have one table in my database and want to add the other one.

The table i have:

```
create table department(
    dept_name varchar(20),
    building varchar(20) not null,
    budget numeric(8,2),
    primary key (dept_name)
)
```

and i want to add this table:

```
create table student (
    ID varchar(5),
    name varchar(20) not null,
    dept_name varchar(20),
    tot_cred numeric(3,0),
    primary key (ID),
    foreign key (dept_name) references department
)
```

But i get this error:

```
#1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint
```

Can you guys help me with this problem? 
Thanks.

Comment: syntax is wrong, your missing the field name it is referencing

Comment: can you show me the right one? please :)

Comment: `foreign key (dept_name) references department ( dept_name )`

Comment: it's working, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your 2nd table should be-

```
create table student (
    ID varchar(5),
    name varchar(20) not null,
    dept_name varchar(20),
    tot_cred numeric(3,0),
    primary key (ID),
    foreign key (dept_name) references department(dept_name)
)
```

Note: It will be better include dept_id as int in your parent table and create reference it in 2nd table to get better performance.

create tables as per below-

```
create table department(
    dept_id int auto_increment,
    dept_name varchar(20),
    building varchar(20) not null,
    budget numeric(8,2),
    primary key (dept_id)
);

create table student (
    ID varchar(5),
    name varchar(20) not null,
    dept_it int,
    tot_cred numeric(3,0),
    primary key (ID),
    foreign key (dept_id) references department(dept_id)
)
```

Comment: in second table also id should be int instead of varchar if not a specific reason also can keep auto_increment.